# Why this element is "undefined" -- it clearly exists

Tags: jscript

I am getting what seems to be a very odd error in a web page.  This is happening in both VS2008 and VS2012.  In the following:

```
<div class="content_header" onclick="tierMenu(menu2,img2)">
    <img id="img2" alt="Colapse Trips" height="9" src="Images/plus.gif" width="9" />
    Travel Summary
</div>
```

clicking the plus image is supposed to change the image to a minus (expanding the item to display data).  The tierMenu javascript method is called upon clicking, and it exists.  But I am getting an error:

> 0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'img2' is undefined

"Img2" definitely exists.  There is similar code in other places in the page, and they all behave the same way -- getting the same error.  Odd thing is, the code is working fine in production.  It's calling:

```
function tierMenu(objMenu,objImage)
{
   if(objMenu && objImage)
   {
    ...
   }
}
```

It happens that my dev machine is 64-bit Windows 7.  I can't imagine that this would be a problem.  Any ideas?

**Edited to Add**: A colleague whose workstation is Win XP tried this on VS2008 and the problem did not occur.  Really odd.  The problem occurs on my workstation even when running outside of Visual Studio, i.e. directly from the browser using localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a browser compatibility issue.  If I put IE9 into compatibility mode the problem goes away.

It isn't the first time compatibility has beat me over the head.  I will have to learn to try that first thing as soon as something weird like this happens.

Thanks to everyone who looked at this and puzzled over it with me.